# Script for deleting files whose name do not contain certain phrases?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, find, rm

If I had a folder of files, what script could I write to remove the files whose names don't have certain phrases?

My folder contains

```
oneApple.zip
twoApples.zip
threeApples.zip
fourApples.zip
```

I would want to remove the files whose names don't contain "one" or "three" anywhere within their filename.

After executing the script, the folder would only contain:

```
oneApple.zip
threeApples.zip
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Using bash

With a modern bash with `extglob` enabled, we can delete files whose names do not contain `one` or `three` with:

```
rm !(*one*|*three*)
```

To experiment with how extglobs work, just use echo:

```
$ echo !(*one*|*three*)
fourApples.zip  twoApples.zip
```

If the above doesn't work properly, then either your bash is out of date or extglob is turned off.  To turn it on:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

#### Using find

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*one*' ! -name '*three*' -delete
```

Before running that command, you probably want to test it.  Just remove the `-delete` and it will show you the files that it found:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*one*' ! -name '*three*'
./twoApples.zip
./fourApples.zip
```

How it works:

- `.`

  This tells `find` to look in the current directory.
- `-maxdepth 1`

  This tells `find` not to recurse into subdirectories
- `-type f`

  This tells `find` that we only want regular files.
- `! -name '*one*'`

  This tells `find` to exclude files with `one` in their name.
- `! -name '*three*'`

  This tells `find` to exclude files with `three` in their name.
- `-delete`

  This tells `find` to delete the files that it found.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your comments were very helpful.